# How to compare multiple variables with else if statement?

Tags: c++

I'm a beginner in C++. I've been given a homework from school to make some practices. One of them is to compare 3 variables typed by the user and make the program print on the screen which number is bigger or smaller. The problem is that every time I run the code, the program always prints the first typed number, even if it doesn't fulfill the condition.  Here is a sample of the code. I looked everywhere and I cannot understand what is wrong.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int var1 = 0;
int var2 = 0;
int var3 = 0;

int main()
{
    cout << "Write 3 integer numbers" << endl;
    cin >> num1 >> num2 >> num3;

    if (var1 < var2,var3)
    {
        cout << num1 << " is smaller"<< endl;
    }

    else if (var2 < var1,var3)
    {
        cout << num2 << " is smaller"<< endl;
    }

    else if (var3 < var1,var2)
    {
        cout << num3 << " is smaller"<< endl;
    }

    system("pause");


}
```

Comment: You can't use the comma like that.

Comment: `var2 < var1 && var2 < var3`

Comment: In expressions, the `,` operator evaluates its two operands and returns the result of the second operand. So your first two `if` statements are only testing whether `var3` is nonzero, and similarly with the last one.

Answer (score 1):

Judging from your code, I'm assuming you want to find the smallest of 3 numbers. However, using a comma is **not** the right way to do it, as the comma is an operand used for other purposes.

If you want to compare multiple variables in a single if-statement condition, then it should be done by using the following template (it's messy, but I'll explain it):

```
if ((variable_1 [operator] variable_2) [AND/OR/NOT operator] (variable_1 [operator] variable_3) ...)
```

- `variable_n` where n represents a number, indicates the variables that can be compared in the if-statement.
- The `[operator]` indicates the various comparison operators that can be used, like <, >, <=, etc...
- The `[AND/OR/NOT operator]` is the operators "||", "&&" or "!" that are used.
- The (...) means you can include more comparisons.

The `&&` operator, known as the logic AND operator, is the one you should use. With this operator, only when both of the comparisons on either side of the "&&" is true does the expression returns true. It follows the syntax:

```
(x > y) && (x > z) // Only if x is greater than y and z will the expression return true.
```

I've fixed the code for you below (there were many errors besides the if-statement:

```
int main()
{
    // These variables don't have to be global for your case
    int var1 = 0;
    int var2 = 0;
    int var3 = 0;

    cout << "Write 3 integer numbers" << endl;
    cin >> var1 >> var2 >> var3; // You don't need num1, num2, num3.

    if ((var1 < var2) && (var1 < var3))
        cout << var1 << " is smaller"<< endl; // If there is only 1 statement in your if-condition, then curly braces are unrequired, just a styling tip I like.

    // I don't want to give the full solutions here, as this is your learning experience. Just fixed dome other errors in your code. You can use the first if-statement to do the other else-if statements.

    system("pause");
}
```

Apart from the if-statement, I'll point out the other errors in your code:

- Firstly, why have you declared `var1`, `var2`, and `var3` as global variables, outside of your main function? It is not wrong (the code will work fine even if they are global variables), but in your case, it is unrequired.
- Secondly, you compare the variables `var1`, `var2`, and `var3` in your if-conditions. However, they are set to zero, and you take input in 3 completely different variables, `num1`, `num2`, `num3`. This leaves `var1`, `var2`, and `var3` unchanged, resulting in a comparison between 0, 0, and 0. You do not need `num1`, `num2`, `num3`.
- Thirdly, the logic itself of your code is prone to errors, particularly when some of the numbers input are the same. Try inputting (1, 1, 1) or (1, 1, 2). I've not fixed this, as it would involve changing a lot of the code itself.

---

As an aside, if you were wondering what the comma operator does, I've explained it below:

[Source: Operators - C++ Tutorials]
(http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/operators/)

The comma operator (,) is used to separate multiple expressions that are found as a placeholder of a single expression. When the set of expressions are evaluated to give an end result, the expression that is to the far-most right is used. See this example:

```
int number, number2;
number2 = (number = 5, number += 7, number / 4);
cout << number2 << endl;
```

What this does here is that 2 variables `number` and `number2` are declared here. In the next line, `number2` is number divided by 4, which was originally set at 5 and then incremented by 7. The third line outputs 4, as (5 + 7)/4 = 3.

Hope this helps. If you need any further explanation, clarification, or something is unclear, please inform me in the post. Good luck!